# Kivy - Updating Canvas with on_size events not working correctly

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

All I'm trying to do is draw 12 circles, and keep them centered in the window.

I have a `FloatLayout` which holds a `BoxLayout`. The `BoxLayout` should "hold" the 12 circles.

Since I want the circles in a row, the `BoxLayout`'s width should be 12 times it's height. The `FloatLayout` resizes the `BoxLayout` so this is always the case. (`FloatLayout` is green, `BoxLayout` is red).

[image: correctly_drawn]

The problem occurs when I resize the window small enough. Now the circles are not centered in the `BoxLayout`. The circles also "jump" left to right as I resize the window (making it look totally unsmooth).

[image: incorrectly_drawn1]

Also, if I maximize the window (instead of resizing by dragging an edge or corner of the window) then it draws the circles where ever.

[image]

Any clue whats happening here?  I am using the `BoxLayout`'s lower left (x,y) coordinates to start drawing circles. The leftmost circle should use the same exact coordinates, but obviously it's off.

Instead of binding the canvas instructions to the `on_size` event with `self.bind(size=self.update_canvas, pos=self.update_canvas)`, I also tried calling `self.redraw_note_markers` at the end of `self.on_size`. That way, when we're drawing the circles, the inner `BoxLayout` should have already been resized.  But that is producing the same result as shown above.

**UPDATE**
I've incorporated this into a larger app, where it is part of a `TabbedPanel`, and these circles are getting drawn totally out of place.

```
# filename: keysigdisplay.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import InstructionGroup, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.clock import Clock


class KeySigDisplay(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # To get note_markers drawn in center of self.ids.box, need super() at top
        # of __init__ and then Clock.schedule_once(self.redraw_note_markers)...?
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.note_markers = InstructionGroup()
        self.bind(size=self.update_canvas, pos=self.update_canvas)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_canvas)

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        self.redraw_note_markers()

    def redraw_note_markers(self, *args):
        self.canvas.remove(self.note_markers)
        self.note_markers.clear()
        x, y = self.ids.box.pos
        for i in range(12):
            self.redraw_note_marker(i, x, y)
        self.canvas.add(self.note_markers)

    def redraw_note_marker(self, i, x, y):
        white = Color(1, 1, 1, 1)  # white
        blue = Color(68 / 255, 93 / 255, 209 / 255, 1)  # blue
        black = Color(0, 0, 0, 1)

        # Draw 2 concentric circles, c1 and c2.
        # Circles are defined by a square's lower left corner.
        r1 = self.ids.box.height / 2
        r2 = r1 * 0.9
        rdiff = r1 - r2
        c1x, c1y = (2*r1)*i + x, y
        c2x, c2y = c1x + rdiff, c1y + rdiff

        self.note_markers.add(white)
        self.note_markers.add(Ellipse(pos=[c1x, c1y], size=[2 * r1, 2 * r1]))
        self.note_markers.add(blue)
        self.note_markers.add(Ellipse(pos=[c2x, c2y], size=[2 * r2, 2 * r2]))

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        width, height = self.size
        target_ratio = 12
        if width / height > target_ratio:
            self.ids.box.height = height
            self.ids.box.width = height * target_ratio
        else:
            self.ids.box.width = width
            self.ids.box.height = width / target_ratio


class KeySigDisplayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KeySigDisplay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KeySigDisplayApp().run()
```

```
# filename: keysigdisplay.kv
<KeySigDisplay>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: [0, 1, 0, 0.25]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        size_hint: [None, None]
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 0, 0, 0.25]
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly for me. What versions of kivy and python are you using? What OS are you using?

Comment: Python version 3.6.4, Kivy version 1.11.1 on Windows10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I was not able to get to the root of the problem. The `FloatLayout`'s `on_size` event should 1) resize the `BoxLayout` and 2) update the canvas based on the size/position change of the `BoxLayout`. It does (1) just fine, but seems to lag with (2).  The changes are not in sync.  The result is graphics "jumping" around as the window is resized, and being just a little off.  I still am unsure why it is behaving this way.

The work-around I'm using is to bind to the `BoxLayout`'s position, and update the canvas there.

```
# filename: keysigdisplay.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import InstructionGroup, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty


class KeySigDisplay(FloatLayout):
    # Added all these properties. box_pos is bound to box.pos in kv file.
    box_x = NumericProperty(0)
    box_y = NumericProperty(0)
    box_pos = ReferenceListProperty(box_x, box_y)  

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.note_markers = InstructionGroup()

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        self.redraw_note_markers()

    def redraw_note_markers(self, *args):
        self.canvas.remove(self.note_markers)
        self.note_markers.clear()
        x, y = self.ids.box.pos
        for i in range(12):
            self.redraw_note_marker(i, x, y)
        self.canvas.add(self.note_markers)

    def redraw_note_marker(self, i, x, y):
        white = Color(1, 1, 1, 1)  # white
        blue = Color(68 / 255, 93 / 255, 209 / 255, 1)  # blue
        black = Color(0, 0, 0, 1)

        # Draw 2 concentric circles, c1 and c2.
        # Circles are defined by a square's lower left corner.
        r1 = self.ids.box.height / 2
        r2 = r1 * 0.9
        rdiff = r1 - r2
        c1x, c1y = (2*r1)*i + x, y
        c2x, c2y = c1x + rdiff, c1y + rdiff

        self.note_markers.add(white)
        self.note_markers.add(Ellipse(pos=[c1x, c1y], size=[2 * r1, 2 * r1]))
        self.note_markers.add(blue)
        self.note_markers.add(Ellipse(pos=[c2x, c2y], size=[2 * r2, 2 * r2]))

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        width, height = self.size
        target_ratio = 12
        if width / height > target_ratio:
            self.ids.box.height = height
            self.ids.box.width = height * target_ratio
        else:
            self.ids.box.width = width
            self.ids.box.height = width / target_ratio

    # Added this method to receive the event.
    def on_box_pos(self, instance, value):
        self.update_canvas(instance, value)

class KeySigDisplayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KeySigDisplay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KeySigDisplayApp().run()
```

```
# filename: keysigdisplay.kv
<KeySigDisplay>:
    box_pos: box.pos
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: [0, 1, 0, 0.25]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        size_hint: [None, None]
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 0, 0, 0.25]
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Not sure if this is the *right* way to be doing this, but it works.  Hopefully someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', 0)
```

at the top of your `keysigdisplay.py`. This will mean that `kivy` will maximize its cpu usage and produce the smoothest display that it can. The default value for `maxfps` is `60` (fps). If this improves your app's graphics performance, you can then try different values of `maxfps` to balance between cpu usage and graphics smoothness.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.  Good tip though.